Using Node's http/2 client functions with webpack
I have been stuck on this for two days now and I'm just absolutely tired of it. Whenever I try to import "node:http2" specifically for using its client side functionality, the application bricks because http2 is removed from the webpack bundle. I'm working with NextJS right now, but the reality is that it's just for convenience's sake. Problem is, I'd still be working with React either way, so I'd be encountering the same issue even if I started over from scratch.
Basically, I need to know how to pull the "node:http2" module in for client side use within React, ideally within the normal webpack functionality, very ideally within NextJS's functionality.
EDIT: I am trying to connect to the streaming functionality specifically, so solutions that don't provide me with the initialization of a stream aren't going to work here. The reason I'm trying to use the available frontend functionality within Node's http2 module is that there's already a whole section in the Node docs about how this works.
expectation: imported node's http2 module with import http2 from "node:http2"
result: http2 is undefined
Tried: using browserify, node-loader, and node-polyfill-webpack-plugin and multiple styles of webpack configurations with externals, resolve, trying to use dynamic importing, etc. and nothing has changed beyond occasionally allowing it to run without crashing, but still undefined.

You cannot; why do you (think) you need this?

Node specifically lists the client side functionalities, and I'm trying to keep the functions matched against the backend architecture using their provided documentation. Note sections like https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#class-clienthttp2stream

@tkausl What I'm needing is to create a duplex stream client side, utilizing the available http/2 streaming functionality to produce a persistent data link for certain functionalities within the application. I could use websockets, but I'm trying to figure out how to perform this with HTTP/2's inbuilt functionality.

Client side doesn't mean in the browser. It means on client side nodejs.

The http2 module will not work in the client side. These modules use raw TCP sockets that browsers simply do not have.
On the browser side, to use HTTP2 you simply need to us fetch(). If you server supports HTTP2, it will automatically be used.

First, there is a whole section in the Node docs on client side use, so this isn't really accurate. Secondly, I am unclear on how fetch would initiate a stream
